# I can't ssh to my Amazon AWS Ubuntu instance using a newly created user and a key pair?

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, amazon-ec2

I created a user called `grader` to my instance and gave it sudo permission, also I switched the password in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to be off.

I generated a key pair in my local machine and added the public key to the instance. When I try to access the instance using the DEFAULT user provided by Amazon AWS and my generated keys it works

```
ssh -i "udacityLinux" ubuntu@ec2-18-218-9-117.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

but when I try the same using the `grader` user I get this error:

```
ssh -i "udacityLinux" grader@ec2-18-218-9-117.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
grader@ec2-18-218-9-117.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

How can I fix this to be able to login using my `grader` user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a misunderstanding about the public key you upload to the server.

This key must be stored in the file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` for every user that should be identified by this key.

This path `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` is equivalent to your current user directory, if you are logged in as `grader` user, that path will point to:

```
/home/grader/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

In case you are logged in as `ubuntu` user, that path will point to:

```
/home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

So for now you could copy the key file with:

```
sudo cp /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys /home/grader/.ssh/
```

Then set the correct owner and permissions:

```
sudo chown grader:grader /home/grader/.ssh/authorized_keys
sudo chmod 0600 /home/grader/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Keep in mind that now you accept all keys that you might have enabled for the user `ubuntu` for the user `grader` as well.